github copilot sigin faild. Request signInInitiate failed
error info
Sign in failed. Reason: Request signInInitiate failed with message: Response content-type is text/plain; charset=utf-8 (status=401), request id: 154, error code: -32603
version
mac
WebStorm 2024.3.1
github copilot 1.5.30-242

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
